# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. (C#)

Tags: c#, android, view, xamarin

I've seen a bunch of similar questions as this but so far all I've seen hasn't helped my problem (mostly because it is in Java, while as I use C#).

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainV2);

    if (IsThereAnAppToTakePictures())
    {
        CreateDirectoryForPictures();
        btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.Click += DialogAddPhoto;
    }

    myFileListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Drawable.style_listview);
    listViewFiles = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
}

private void DialogAddPhoto(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // passing intent i.e. REQUEST_CAMERA, SELECT_FILE
}
```

Where I get the problem...

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    _imageView = new ImageView(this);
    btnRemove = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRemove);

    if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
        {
            // ................. //
        }
        else if ((requestCode == SELECT_FILE) && (data != null))
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
            string imgUri = Convert.ToString(uri);

            string[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data };
            var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
            var colIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data);
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options { InJustDecodeBounds = true };
            BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(cursor.GetString(colIndex), options);
            int height = 300;
            int width = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
            int outHeight = options.OutHeight;
            int outWidth = options.OutWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (outHeight > height || outWidth > width)
                {
                    inSampleSize = outWidth > outHeight
                                       ? outHeight / height
                                       : outWidth / width;
                }

             options.InSampleSize = inSampleSize;
             options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
             App.bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(cursor.GetString(colIndex), options);
             System.IO.MemoryStream mem = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
             App.bm.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, mem);
             //byte[] byteArray = mem.ToArray();
             _imageView.SetImageBitmap(App.bm);
             App.bm = null;
             GC.Collect();

             myFileListAdapter.Add(imgUri);
             myFileListAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
             setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listViewFiles);

             listViewFiles.ItemClick += (object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) =>
             {
                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                 builder.SetTitle("Preview");                        
                 builder.SetView(_imageView);
                 builder.SetCancelable(false);
                 builder.SetPositiveButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) => { });
                 builder.SetNegativeButton("Delete?", (senderAlert, args) =>
                 {

                     Java.Lang.Object toRemove = myFileListAdapter.GetItem(e.Position);
                     myFileListAdapter.Remove(toRemove);
                     myFileListAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                     setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listViewFiles);

                 });

                 builder.Show();
                };

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the culprit.

```
builder.SetView(_imageView);
```

I tried doing this but still gets me the same error.

```
builder.SetView(null);
builder.SetView(_imageView);
```

What it does is after selecting or adding an image from the gallery, the `Uri`is added to the list (`ListView`). That item which upon clicking, an Alert Dialog box will appear where the image (`_imageView`) is seen. The error happens after clicking the `Cancel` and viewing the `Uri`image after `Deleting and Adding` another one from the gallery.

All of the solutions I've seen use Inflate and I honestly have no idea how to incorporate that on my code because the imageview depends on a dynamic value (imported image from gallery).

Please note that I am using Xamarin Android.

Trace:

```
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3430)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3301)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3277)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:416)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:244)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:337)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:355)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:260)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at mono.android.widget.AdapterView_OnItemClickListenerImplementor.n_onItemClick(Native Method)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at mono.android.widget.AdapterView_OnItemClickListenerImplementor.onItemClick(AdapterView_OnItemClickListenerImplementor.java:29)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1128)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2815)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3574)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-27 17:51:54.434 E/mono-rt (16678):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you please add the Stack Trace to your answer ?

Comment: @YumeYume I just did. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image view is already assigned to a parent create a new image view and set it

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                 builder.SetTitle("Preview");  
 var temp= new ImageView(this);   
temp.SetImageBitmap(App.bm);                   
                 builder.SetView(temp);
                 builder.SetCancelable(false);
                 builder.SetPositiveButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) => { });
                 builder.SetNegativeButton("Delete?", (senderAlert, args) =>
                 {

                     Java.Lang.Object toRemove = myFileListAdapter.GetItem(e.Position);
                     myFileListAdapter.Remove(toRemove);
                     myFileListAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                     setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listViewFiles);

                 });

                 builder.Show();
                };
```

Comment: This seems to work and I don't get the error anymore but after adding another image, the dialogbox for viewing the image is duplicating. For instance, I add a photo then I viewed it, after deleting it, I add another one. When I viewed it then click cancel, the dialogbox of the previous added image was there. This is so confusing me.

Comment: Another one is when I add many photos, when I click it one by one, the latest added photo is the only one appearing on the dialogbox.

Comment: Please do un bind your event handlers with -= the same way you add with += and also dismiss the dialogue when you delete

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. What event handler should I need to unbind? Like this: `listViewFiles.ItemClick -= (object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)`? There seems no option to dismiss the `AlertDialog.Builder` as well? I'm new to this so I hope you don't mind.

Comment: listViewFiles.ItemClick += ClickHandler;....}

ClickHandler(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e){...}
listViewFiles.ItemClick -= ClickHandler

Comment: I made some changes to my code but I still get a bug in the dialog box. I'm posting the question in another thread. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, please see this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073137/dialogbox-bug-xamarin-android) I posted another question regarding the bugs I'm encountering.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

I had a similar problem in WPF. The steps how i solved it (code is for WPF, the API might be different in XAMARIN):

1. Get the reference to the child i need. 
   `Grid contentGrid = page.ContentGrid;`
2. Remove the child from its parent (kinda sad). The parent in my case is a grid called `MainGrid`: `page.MainGrid.Children.Remove(contentGrid);`

It looks that in your case the `Remove()` method of the `Children` collection si called `RemoveView()` because they call controls "views", which i personally hate.

Comment: I honestly don't know where to get the reference and what Parent should I use. Is it the `ImageView` or the `AlertDialog`?